# Saving ALL nested documents on parent update Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My parent model looks like this:

```
var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    serviceNotes: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Service'},
    vehicle: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Vehicle'}
});
```

The children look like this:

```
var VehicleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var ServiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    baseCost: Number
});
```

I am trying to find an easy solution to updating all of these documents at once. The problem is, when I call an update on an order, it does not update the nested documents. Please see the following:

```
exports.updateOrder = function (req, res) {
  var order = req.body.order,
      update = {
        $set: order
      };

  Order.findOneAndUpdate({_id: order._id}, update, {new: true}, function (err, order) {
    if (err) handleError(res);
    if (!order) return res.status(404).send('Order not found.');
    return res.json({order: order});
  });
}
```

An example of `req.body` in this case may look like this:

```
{
    order: {
        _id: 829198218932shdbn,
        serviceNotes: {
            _id: 8932838nsd2sdnbd,
            baseCost: 1
        },
        vehicle: {
            _id: iu283823872378bd,
            name: 'Honda'
        }
    }
}
```

The order update should also update the serviceNotes with the updated information, and the vehicle with the updated information.

The only way I have been able to update the nested documents is by calling a `findOneAndUpdate` on the children and updating them one by one. I am looking for a solution to just call update on the parent (order) and have the children update as well.

Comment: Update what exactly? What information is supposed to update? Basically though you want "cascading" updates, which is done in a middleware hook, either pre or post save, or update.

Comment: @NeilLunn please see my updated question. I provided an example of what the body would look like and what should save on update.

Comment: In all honesty it looks like you are trying to "update" the wrong thing. The detail you actually want to update resides in separate models, so in fact you should be issuing your update to those instead. Of greater worry is that this looks "very relational" in design, for a product that is "not relational". So either your thinking should change or you should change database engines.